# Java - Pulling line animation lags and invisible

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I have a problem in my program with the custom drawing part.
I want the user to click on the interface and then drag while the program draw a line which follow the cursor.
But the problem is, I can barely see it. Also, the line won't stay after the cursor's button release.
[image: example]

Custom draw line code:

```
public void drawTemporaryLine(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,ArrayList<Line> lines){
    repaint();
    g2d = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    for(Line l:lines){
        g2d.drawLine(l.getX1(),l.getY1(),l.getX2(),l.getY2());
    }
    g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Mouse listener code:

```
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(draw_on){
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        if(draw_on){
            drawPanel.drawTemporaryLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY(),lines);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        if(draw_on){
            lines.add(new Line(x,y,e.getX(),e.getY()));
            optionButtons[0].setSelected(false);
            draw_on = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics`, this is not how custom painting should be done.  You should be storing the values you need (x1, y1, x2, y2) in some instance fields and using `paintComponent` method to paint them, calling `repaint` when you want the UI updated

Comment: See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: Your problem is, that your line is only painted if you drag, but the graphics of the frame are painted in background and draw over your line, so it disapears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override `paintComponent`.

I tried to reproduce it myself:

Try this :)

DrawPanel (extends JPanel)

```
private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
private Line tmpLine = null;

public DrawPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

public void drawTemporaryLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    tmpLine = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

public void setTemporaryLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    lines.add(new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2));
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    for (Line l : lines) {
        g2d.drawLine(l.getX1(), l.getY1(), l.getX2(), l.getY2());
    }
    if (tmpLine != null) {
        g2d.drawLine(tmpLine.getX1(), tmpLine.getY1(), tmpLine.getX2(), tmpLine.getY2());
    }
}
```

NewJFrame (extends JFrame):

```
private DrawPanel draw = new DrawPanel();
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setSize(800,600);

    add(draw);
    draw.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            draw.setTemporaryLine(x, y, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            draw.repaint();
        }
        public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            x = evt.getX();
            y = evt.getY();
        }
    });
    draw.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            draw.drawTemporaryLine(x, y, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            draw.repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! It worked. Now I'm not gonna use getGraphics() anymore. ;)